# back_inserter error for vector

Tags: c++, stl

I am reading STL tutorial at following link

http://cs.brown.edu/people/jak/proglang/cpp/stltut/tut.html

How to fix compilation error?

Here following code is mentioned

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
void iota_n (ForwardIterator first, int n, T value)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      *first++ = *value++;
  }
}


void main ()
{

  vector<int> v;
  iota_n (v.begin(), 100, back_inserter(v));

  random_shuffle (v.begin(), v.end());                         // shuffle
  copy (v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int> (cout, "\n")); // print

}
```

While compiling facing following error.

error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::back_insert_iterator<_Container>' to 'int'

Comment: Whoever taught you `void main` ignore them from now on and look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282) instead.

Comment: @nwp ... and `using namespace std;`, and `std::random_shuffle`, and `<stdlib.h>` :p

Comment: Stop reading that thing. It went outdated about 20 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
void iota_n (ForwardIterator first, int n, T value)
```

This prototype requires the iterator as the first argument, but you're passing it as the initial value instead.

When you replace the `iota_n` call with

```
iota_n (back_inserter(v), 100, 42);
```

and fix the assignment inside the function:

```
*first++ = value++;
```

You'll get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Got the mistake